# Mineflayer (minecraft-data;pathfinder): Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, minecraft, mineflayer

So I´ve been trying to make a bot that followes my Minecraft character `(playerCI = bot.players["Cyberyes"])`, but when I try to start it, I get this error:

> Starting...
> C:\Users\Jakob\Documents\Minecraft\Bot\FirstBot\node_modules\mineflayer-pathfinder\lib\movements.js:35
> this.blocksCantBreak.add(mcData.blocksByName.chest.id)
> ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'blocksByName')
> at new Movements (C:\Users\Jakob\Documents\Minecraft\Bot\FirstBot\node_modules\mineflayer-pathfinder\lib\movements.js:35:37)
> at EventEmitter.followPlayer (C:\Users\Jakob\Documents\Minecraft\Bot\FirstBot\main.js:28:23)
> at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:509:28)
> at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:402:35)
> at Client. (C:\Users\Jakob\Documents\Minecraft\Bot\FirstBot\node_modules\mineflayer\lib\plugins\health.js:13:11)
> at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:510:26)
> at Client.emit (node:events:402:35)
> at FullPacketParser. (C:\Users\Jakob\Documents\Minecraft\Bot\FirstBot\node_modules\minecraft-protocol\src\client.js:91:12)
> at FullPacketParser.emit (node:events:390:28)
> at addChunk (C:\Users\Jakob\Documents\Minecraft\Bot\FirstBot\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_readable.js:298:12)

This is my Code:

```
console.log("Starting...")

const mineflayer = require('mineflayer')
const { pathfinder, Movements, goals } = require('mineflayer-pathfinder')
const GoalFollow = goals.GoalFollow


var settings = {
    username: "Bot",
    host: "185.245.96.138",
    port: "25592",
    version: "1.16.5",
    }

const bot = mineflayer.createBot(settings)
bot.loadPlugin(pathfinder)

function followPlayer() {
    const playerCI = bot.players['Cyberyes']

    if (!playerCI || !playerCI.entity) {
        bot.chat("I can't see Cyberyes!")
        return
    }


    const mcData = require('minecraft-data')(bot.version)
    const movements = new Movements(bot, mcData)
    bot.pathfinder.setMovements(movements)

    const goal = new GoalFollow(playerCI.entity, 1)
    bot.pathfinder.setGoal(goal, true)
}

bot.once("spawn", followPlayer)
```

Comment: Can you show your json with dependencies ? Specially to know which version you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same Error I could Fix this, with a funktion like this
My code is in Python, but shouldnt be much diffrent JavaScript

```py
def initMovement():
        movements = pathfinder.Movements(bot)

        #If you want to Deactivate sth
        movements.canDig = False

        bot.pathfinder.setMovements(movements)
```

this funktion is called after the bot is spawned